# Excel 2010 Convert text string to Full date & 24 hr time

Tags: excel, date, excel-2010

**Program:**  Excel 2010
**Issue:**    External report gives me a text string, I want to convert it to Date & 24 hour time.

```
141221205535  needs to be:
14/12/21 20:55:35
```

I have tried text to columns making the result show:  YMD
I have then tried using the format cells option: (custom)  yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss
*  I receive a string of ######## in the Sample field in the formatting box.

I have tried also just using the date/time version, no seconds

```
1412212055  needs to be:
14/12/21 20:55
```

ideally, if possible:

```
20141421 2055 or 2014/14/21 20:55 I will accept
```

I can not alter the report as it comes through a 3rd party and I am pulling the date from a 'reference' field.  The report, when downloaded, is in CSV and there is no existing formatting on the data.

I need to convert this as my sales report then needs to be sorted by date order.

**Note:**  If I do use the seconds in the string, I get the weird looking scientific number. So i've had to reduce the digits, this isn't ideal, is there a way to avoid the scientific number whilst the process of changing 'text to date' is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No existing formatting? So it's "general"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula like this would work -

```
=TEXT(DATE(LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,3,2),MID(A1,5,2))+TIME(MID(A1,7,2),MID(A1,9,2),MID(A1,11,2)),"yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")
```

If your format always has 12 digits

Comment: thank you, that works.  I've been trying to use the code to also enter it without the ss, what would be the answer with only 10 digits, 0 seconds, please?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MrsAdmin just remove the `:ss` from the end of the formula

Comment: Thank you, it still showed an error, but recounted the steps inwards and deleted 'MID(A1,11,2)' and it worked, as well as removing the :ss.  It was throwing an error as it was still looking for the final 2 digits in my string.  Thanks so much, I've accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I used this formula to convert:

`=TEXT(A1,"2000-00-00 00\:00\:00")+0`

format result cell in required format, e.g. `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`

If you don't want the seconds in the underlying value you can use this version

`=TEXT(LEFT(A1,10),"2000-00-00 00\:00")+0`

These formulas work because `TEXT` function converts your value `141221205535` to a text value `2014-12-21 20:55:35`, then, because that is a valid date/time format in Excel the **+0** "co-erces" the text value to a serial number representing the correct date/time in Excel.....so you can then simply format the result to display any way you want.

Note that I'm assuming all dates will be in the current (21st) century.....

Comment: Thank you :)  We've decided on implementing the seconds as that allows for a wholly unique referenceID.  I like this answer as I can then format it depending on what stage of my workbook i'm saving it in and I can adjust how I view it.  Excellent work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the `datevalue` with the `timevalue` to get also the HMS

for example (suppose the text is in `D5` cell):

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(D5,2)&"-"&MID(D5,3,2)&-MID(D5,5,2))+TIMEVALUE(MID(D5,7,2)&":"&MID(D5,9,2)&":"&RIGHT(D5,2))`
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I've gone with another answer though. :)